# Finishing activity without onPause called

Tags: android, android-activity

I am finishing my current activity using finish(). This is calling onPause automatically. I want to finish activity without onPause being called. My activity is running a song service so i want song to stop when app is in background but dont want it to stop when user goes from one activity into another in my app. I cant do stopService and startService in between activities because then there is a momentary lag in between the sounds.

Comment: Android will generally call onPause() if you call finish() at some point during your Activity's lifecycle unless you call finish() in your onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface

[google docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

The background `Service` is agnostic of which `Activity` is running or any discontinuity between them.

The two types, "bound" and "started" are supposed to have different persistence characteristics but in practice (not stress testing) I find the bound `Service` does not clobbered for lack of system memory and is much easier to implement (despite tutorials claiming otherwise). It uses some IPC abstraction that appears as though it is being directly invoked from the `Activity`. The same can't be said of the "started" variety (unless it is also bound) which is IMO a closer approximation to the traditional service I would associate with web-servers (or anything that is already going to be experiencing not insignificant delays- such as due to network transmission).

(Lecture over) I see you are calling `finish()`. You need some way to shut down the `Service` from your `Activity`. Just make sure to branch aways from doing so when not intended. Code would be helpful but I can assure you this is how media players work.

Comment: yeah i am using mediaplayer in my service. Stopping and Starting again causes a delay in background music. It deosnt sound good.

Comment: Can I suggest you use a retained `Fragment` to hold your media player?

Comment: Well i would prefer to use another functioninstead of finish() to close activity as well, without calling onPause

Comment: Also its a game so i dont wanna save instance, i just need some substitute to have onPauses as well as destroying previous activity(level) in it.

Comment: `finish()` is the only way I know to stop an activity. But as I said that per se is not going to cause a break in background music. Do you mean break or delay? For gaming and sound effects there might well be a delay in setting up mediaplayer.

Comment: John please answer my this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023062/pause-and-resume-timer-made-using-handlers

Comment: According to me stopService in onPause and start service in onResume causes the break between background music.

Comment: @NimitAggarwal you're the `Handler` expert, I use a `Service` just for my `MediaPlayer`, but it probably would be delayed relative to visual stimulus, as all I do is audio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92568/discussion-between-nimit-aggarwal-and-john).